# How to get physical address of ARM64 Linux page table?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory-address

How can I get the physical address of page table itself?
I tried to use __pa(), virt_to_phys() but it seems to translate to another virtual address.
For example, the address of the page table of the first page is:

0xffffffbf00000000 --> 0x0000003f78800000.
The system has only 5G physical memory.
So, the address must be another virtual address.
How can I get its actual physical address?

Comment: Even if the system only has 5 GB of physical memory, that doesn't necessarily imply that it is mapped (in hardware) at addresses `0-0x140000000`.  So `0x0000003f78800000` isn't necessarily an impossible physical address.

Comment: To see the list of current registered physical addresses do `cat /proc/iomem` if you have that file.

Comment: Thank  you for the replies. 
I'm sorry I didn't include its physical memory addresses.
Its physical memory address is:
0x8000_0000 - 0xBFFF_FFFF  /* low 1G */
0x1_0000_0000 - 0x1_FFFF_FFFF /* high 4G */
so, 0x3f78800000 is out of the ranges.

It doesn't boot now because some issues in hardware. 
So, I cannot use "cat /proc/iomem".
I'm actually debugging page table corruption while Linux boots on our hardware.
Page table get corrupted at booting.
I want to pin point which memory  address is corrupted.